# Selenium Python, parsing through website, opening a new tab, and scraping?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys # keys içerisinden enter yapabilmesini sağlıyoruz
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/EMRE/Desktop/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
import pandas as pd
browser.get("http://event.ybu.edu.tr/kulupler/") #main url
import csv

#browser.fullscreen_window()
#time.sleep(2)


#for i in range(6): 
    #browser.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)') #sayfayı aşağıya doğru çekmek için
    #time.sleep(1)

Kulup_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/a/div/div[1]/div") #ilk kulüp için sonra değiştir
Kulup_button.click()    
time.sleep(1)

for i in range(1): 
    browser.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)') #sayfayı aşağıya doğru çekmek için
    time.sleep(1)


kulupnames = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")
kulupList=[]
for kulupname in kulupnames:
    kulupList.append(kulupname.text)  

mails = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("#bilgiler > a.btn.bg-orange.btn-social")
MailList=[]
for mail in mails:
    MailList.append(mail.text)
    
    
FacebookAdresses = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("#bilgiler > a.btn.bg-blue.btn-social") 
FacebookList=[] 
for FacebookAdress in FacebookAdresses: 
   FacebookList.append(FacebookAdress.text)    
    
TwitterAdresses = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("#bilgiler > a.btn.btn-social.bg-aqua") 
TwitterList=[] 
for TwitterAdress in TwitterAdresses: 
   TwitterList.append(TwitterAdress.text) 
   
   
InstagramAdresses = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("#bilgiler > a.btn.btn-social.bg-light-blue") 
InstagramList=[] 
for InstagramAdress in InstagramAdresses:
   InstagramList.append(InstagramAdress.text)
   

AkademikDanismanlar = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")
DanismanList=[] 
for AkademikDanisman in AkademikDanismanlar: 
   DanismanList.append(AkademikDanisman.text)      

KulupBaskanlari = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]")
BaskanList=[] 
for KulupBaskani in KulupBaskanlari: 
   BaskanList.append(KulupBaskani.text)  

ToplamUyeler = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]")
UyeList=[] 
for Uye in ToplamUyeler: 
   UyeList.append(Uye.text)  

Etkinlikler = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]")
EtkinlikList=[] 
for Etkinlik in Etkinlikler: 
   EtkinlikList.append(Etkinlik.text)  


time.sleep(2)

browser.quit()


#DataFile = csv.writer(open('AYBU.csv','w'))
#DataFile.writerow(['KulupAdi','MailAdresi','FacebookAdresi','TwitterAdresi','InstagramAdresi','AkademikDanisman','KulupBaskani','ToplamUyeSayisi','ToplamEtkinlikSayisi'])
#DataFile.to_csv("AYBU.csv", index = False, encoding='utf-8-sig')


liste = {'kulupList':kulupList,'MailList':MailList,'FacebookList':FacebookList,'TwitterList':TwitterList,'InstagramList':InstagramList,'DanismanList':DanismanList,'BaskanList':BaskanList,'UyeList':UyeList,'EtkinlikList':EtkinlikList}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = liste)
df.to_csv("AYBU.csv", index = False, encoding='utf-8-sig')



*emphasized text*
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Can you post the minimal code that shows what goes wrong?

Comment: Do you see any error? Which line?

Comment: When opening the club, I want to open it on the new page, I  say Switch to the new page in the code, I will pull the data and close the new page and say skip the old page, Then I will click on the next club. How can I make these commands in my codes this is my exact question. My codes are working properly but these are only scrap one of the clubs data. There are more than 50 student clubs which I should scrap, then I should save all scrap data in CSV file.